# Manipulate the DOM with jQuery just before the page loads

Tags: 8, javascript

Because of accesibility tests i need to manipulate the html of my page just before it loads completely. I dont want to manipulate *contrib* modules i am using, so i need to do it with *jQuery*.
In fact, i think the way i'm doing it changes the page when it loads completely so the online accesibility tools i use don't see my changes. I'm using the following:

```
  Drupal.behaviors.bcsc = {
    attach: function (context, settings) {
      $(document).ready(function () {
              /******/
              //here my code
              /******/
      },//end function
    };//end behaviour
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

will changing `$(document).ready(function ()` for `$(document).beforeReady(function ()` work?

Comment: The `attach` method for a behavior is already executed after DOM ready, so adding `ready` or `beforeReady` in there won't do anything

Comment: Do the accessibility tools execute JavaScript?

Comment: yes, the accesibility tools i use do support Javascript